# AJAX & PHP: Display search result on DataTable of GET request from form submitting

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable, laravel-blade

I have form to search any person in database.
Then I want to display the search result in DataTable.

I am using blade for templating HTML.

This is my form:

```
<form id="myform" method="GET" action="{{ site_url('person/search') }}">
```

This is my DataTable section in my HTML

```
<section class="panel" style="margin-top:20px;">
         @include(config_item('theme').'.person.part.table-person', compact('result'), ['id' => 'persons'])
</section>
```

This is my table:

```
<table id="{{ $id }}" data-toggle="table" data-mobile-responsive="true">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="image" data-align="center">Image</th>
            <th data-field="id" data-visible="false">ID</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

And for the last is my AJAX code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myform').submit(function() { 
            $.ajax({
                dataType: json, 
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                type: $(this).attr('method'),
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                success: function(response) { 
                    $('#persons').html(response); 
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

With all that codes, I can't display the search result.

am I doing something wrong? 
Thanks

Comment: what is the returned data of response?

Comment: `dataType: 'JSON'` between quotes

Answer (score 0):

make sure .. you cant duplicate same id name
use jQ append to display table detail

```
$('#channels').append(' <tr>
        <th data-field="image" data-align="center">Image</th>
        <th data-field="id" data-visible="false">ID</th>
    </tr>');
```

HINT : http://api.jquery.com/append/